# Is it possible to restrict "pinch and zoom" in echo3D webAR experience?

Tags: 3d, augmented-reality, pinchzoom, 3d-model, web-ar

I'm using echo3D to showcase 3D models for a client but I am wondering if/how it's possible to limit how viewers interact with the WebAR experience? Can I turn off “pinch and zoom” and restrict movement, they just open the model and that’s that. I tried looking in the docs and couldn't see which variable to edit or where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep that's possible! You can set the maxPitch, maxYaw, and maxFOV metadata to limit movement. See more here:
https://docs.echo3d.com/scene-viewer/deploy-experience#changing-the-default-ar-mode-or-placement
Hope this helps!